# Dojo 1.6.1 custom widget does not go into postCreate in IE9, Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dojo

***(Explanation at the bottom)***

**Helpful:** Lines in code that have a (*) at start and end are the lines that i get a break on.

Hey guys i have a serious issue with a custom dojo widget.

I have the following code (services.aspx):

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="formdojoRequirementsPlaceHolder"
    runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("js.Forms.ServiceDetails");
        dojo.require("js.Forms.PendingServices");
        dojo.require("js.Forms.CertificatesList");

        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            //LOCALIZATION
            var glb_connections = [];
            var ServiceDetailsTab = dijit.byId('ServiceDetails');
            var PendingTaskTab = dijit.byId('PendingTask');
            var PendingServicesTab = dijit.byId('PendingServices');
            var CertificatesListTab = dijit.byId('CertificatesList');
            var MessagesTab = dijit.byId('Messages');

            if (ServiceDetailsTab) { ServiceDetailsTab.attr('title', glb_nlsStrings.ServiceTab) };
            if (PendingTaskTab) { PendingTaskTab.attr('title', glb_nlsStrings.PendingTaskTab) };
            if (PendingServicesTab) { PendingServicesTab.attr('title', glb_nlsStrings.PendingServicesTab) };
            if (CertificatesListTab) { CertificatesListTab.attr('title', glb_nlsStrings.CertificatesTab) };
            if (MessagesTab) { MessagesTab.attr('title', glb_nlsStrings.MessagesTab) };

            ServiceDetailsTab = null;
            PendingTaskTab = null;
            PendingServicesTab = null;
            CertificatesListTab = null;
            MessagesTab = null;
            //

            var queryObj = Utils.General.GetQueryStringObject(window.location.href);
            var organizationId = queryObj[Utils.General.Constants.queryParameters.ORGANIZATIONID];
            var serviceTypeCode = queryObj[Utils.General.Constants.queryParameters.SERVICETYPECODE];

            var tab = queryObj['glb_currentTab'];

            if (dojo.byId("ServiceDetailsWdj") != undefined) {
                *djtServiceDetails.serviceTypeCode = serviceTypeCode;*

                glb_connections.push(dojo.connect(djtPendingServices, "onServiceInstanceDeleted", function() {
                    *djtServiceDetails.onBack();*
                }));

                *glb_connections.push(dojo.connect(djtServiceDetails, "onServiceCompleted", function() {
                    djtPendingServices._FindIncompleteServices(serviceTypeCode, glb_site_userID, organizationId);
                }));*
            }
            else {
                removeTab("ServiceDetails")
            }

            if (dojo.byId("PendingTaskWdj") != undefined) {
                glb_subscriptions.push(dojo.subscribe("_serviceInstanceDeleted", function(child) {
                    *djtPendingServices._FindIncompleteServices(serviceTypeCode, glb_site_userID, organizationId);*
                }));

                glb_connections.push(dojo.connect(djtPendingServices, "onServiceInstanceCompleted", function() {
                    djtPendingServices._FindIncompleteServices(serviceTypeCode, glb_site_userID, organizationId);
                    if (dojo.byId("ServiceDetailsWdj") != undefined) { *djtServiceDetails.postCreate();* }
                }));

                djtPendingServices._FindIncompleteServices(serviceTypeCode, glb_site_userID, organizationId);
            }
            else {
                removeTab("PendingTask")
            }


            removeTab("dataToBeSubmittedTab");

            if (tab != undefined) {
                glb_currentTab = tab;
                var tabContainerWidget = dijit.byId('tabContainer');
                tabContainerWidget.selectChild(glb_currentTab);
            } else {
                glb_currentTab = 'ServiceDetails';
            }

            glb_subscriptions.push(dojo.subscribe("tabContainer-selectChild", function(child) {
                glb_currentTab = child.id;
            }));

        });

        function removeTab(tabId) {
            var tabContainerDijit = dijit.byId("tabContainer");
            if (tabContainerDijit) {
                var dataToBeSubmittedTabDijit = dijit.byId(tabId);
                if (dataToBeSubmittedTabDijit) {
                    tabContainerDijit.removeChild(dataToBeSubmittedTabDijit);
                }
            }
        }

        dojo.addOnUnload(function() {
            if (typeof glb_connections != "undefined")
                dojo.forEach(glb_connections, dojo.disconnect);
            if (typeof glb_subscriptions != "undefined")
                dojo.forEach(glb_subscriptions, dojo.unsubscribe);
        });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="formMainContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <div id="ServiceDetails" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Services" style="height: 95%">
        <div id="divServiceDetails" runat="server">
            <div dojotype="js.Forms.ServiceDetails" jsid="djtServiceDetails" id="ServiceDetailsWdj">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PendingTask" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Pending Tasks" style="height: 95%">
        <div id="divPendingTask" runat="server">
            <div dojotype="js.Forms.PendingServices" jsid="djtPendingServices" id="PendingTaskWdj">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="CertificatesList" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Certificates"
        style="height: 95%">
        <div id="divCertificatesList" runat="server">
            <div dojotype="js.Forms.CertificatesList">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

The 3 files : 1.dojo.require("js.Forms.ServiceDetails");
              2.dojo.require("js.Forms.PendingServices");
              3.dojo.require("js.Forms.CertificatesList");
```

are the widgets.

The widget is build based on MVC.

The important thing here is the view part that the problem occurs so the code of the View follows:

```
dojo.provide("js.Forms.Views.ServiceDetailsView");

dojo.require("js.Forms.Controllers.ServiceDetailsController");
dojo.require("js.FormSteps.FormsList");
dojo.require("js.FormSteps.IncompleteServices");
dojo.require("BL.DataContracts.Entities.FormDefinition");
dojo.require("BL.DataContracts.Entities.ServiceFormInstance");

dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dojox.dtl._DomTemplated");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DropDownButton");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");

dojo.declare("js.Forms.Views.ServiceDetailsView", [dijit._Widget,  dojox.dtl._DomTemplated], {
connections: null,
controller: null,
widgetsInTemplate: true,
templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("js.Forms", "Templates/ServicesList.html"),
servicesList: null,
serviceTypeCode: null,
servicesDefinitions: null,
inCompleteServices: null,
isDissolved: null,

constructor: function() {
    this.controller = new js.Forms.Controllers.ServiceDetailsController(this);
    this.nlsStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("Resources", "Resources");
    var queryObj = Utils.General.GetQueryStringObject(window.location.href);
    this.isDissolved = queryObj[Utils.General.Constants.queryParameters.ISDISSOLVED];
},

**postCreate: function(args, frag) {
    this.inherited("postCreate", arguments);
    this.ConnectEvents();
    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "none");
    if ((this.isDissolved == 'false') || (this.isDissolved == undefined)) {
        this.FindServicesDefinitions();
        this.SetButtonLabels();
    }
},**

SetButtonLabels: function() {
    this.btnBackService.attr('label', this.nlsStrings.btnBack);

},

ConnectEvents: function() {
    this.connect(this.djtIncompleteServices, 'onCreateNewService', function() {
        this.showFormDefinitions();
    });

    this.connect(this.djtIncompleteServices, 'onIncompleteServiceLoad', function(serviceinstanceid, isReturned) {            
        this.djtFormsList.isReturnedService = isReturned;
        this.onFilterDefinitions(serviceinstanceid);
    });

    this.connect(this.djtIncompleteServices, 'onIncompleteServiceDeleted', function(serviceinstanceid) {
        this.onDeleteServiceInstance(serviceinstanceid);
    });

    this.connect(this.djtFormsList, 'onServiceCompleted', function() {
        this._ServiceCompleted();
    });
},

DeleteIncompleteServiceFromModel: function(serviceinstanceid) {
    this.controller.model.incompleteServicesList = dojo.filter(this.controller.model.incompleteServicesList, function(serviceinstance) { return serviceinstance.serviceinstanceid != serviceinstanceid; });
    this.showIncompleteServices(this.controller.model.incompleteServicesList);
    dojo.publish("_serviceInstanceDeleted");
},

onDeleteServiceInstance: function(serviceinstanceid) {
    this.controller.DeleteServiceInstance(serviceinstanceid);
},

FindServicesDefinitions: function() {
    this.controller.FindServices();
},

BindServicesList: function(servicesList) {
    this.servicesList = servicesList;
    this.buildRendering();

    this.ShowServicesList(this.serviceTypeCode);
},

ShowServicesList: function(serviceTypeCode) {
    //debugger;
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "block");

    if (serviceTypeCode == Utils.General.Constants.serviceTypeCode.REGISTRATIONOFORGANIZATION) {
        if (glb_currentRegistrationService) {
            dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "none");
            this.controller.FindIncompleteRegistrationServices();
        }
    }

    this.servicesListHeading.innerHTML = (serviceTypeCode == Utils.General.Constants.serviceTypeCode.CHANGEOFORGANIZATION) ?
                                         this.nlsStrings.colOrganizationChangeServices : this.nlsStrings.colOrganizationChangeServices;
},

BindIncompleteRegistrationServices: function() {
    //debugger;
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "block");
    var incompleteRegistrationServices = this.controller.GetIncompleteRegistrationServices();
    var hasIncompleteRegistrationServices = (incompleteRegistrationServices != null && incompleteRegistrationServices.length > 0);

    dojo.query("a[servicecode]").forEach(function(node) {
        //debugger;
        if (hasIncompleteRegistrationServices) {
            var idx = -1;
            var nodeServiceCode = dojo.attr(node, "servicecode");

            var incompleteRegServices = dojo.filter(incompleteRegistrationServices, function(item) {
                return item.serviceCode == nodeServiceCode;
            });

            if (incompleteRegServices.length == 0) {
                dojo.attr(node, "disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < incompleteRegistrationServices.length; i++) {
                    if (incompleteRegistrationServices[i].serviceCode == nodeServiceCode)
                        idx = i;
                }

                if (idx >= 0) {
                    if (incompleteRegistrationServices[idx].shouldEnable == false)
                        dojo.attr(node, "disabled", "disabled");
                    else
                        node.removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //There are no incomplete regisistrations for the organization name.Disable any subservices.
            if (dojo.attr(node, "servicecode") != glb_currentRegistrationService) {
                dojo.attr(node, "disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
    });
},

onselectService: function(event) {
    var domNode = event.srcElement;

    if (!dojo.hasAttr(domNode, 'disabled')) {
        var serviceCode = dojo.attr(domNode, "serviceCode");

        this.servicesDefinitions = dojo.filter(this.servicesList.OrganizationServices, function(serviceDefinition) { return serviceDefinition.ServiceDefinitionID == serviceCode; });
        if (Utils.General.GetQueryStringObject(window.location.href).organizationid == undefined) {
            this.inCompleteServices = this.controller.FindIncompleteServices(serviceCode, 0);
        }
        else {
            this.inCompleteServices = this.controller.FindIncompleteServices(serviceCode, Utils.General.GetQueryStringObject(window.location.href).organizationid);
        }
    }
},


onFilterDefinitions: function(serviceinstanceid) {
    glb_serviceInstanceID = serviceinstanceid;
    var filteredDefitions = this.controller.FilterFormsDefinitions(serviceinstanceid);
},

DeleteServiceDefinitionFromClient: function(serviceinstanceid) {

},

showFilteredFormDefinitions: function() {
    //debugger;
    var iscomplete = true;
    var modl = this.controller.model.incompleteServiceFormsList;

    var servDefinitions = dojo.clone(this.servicesDefinitions[0]);
    var formsDef = servDefinitions.FormsDefinitions;
    var formCode = null;

    if (servDefinitions.IsVariableFee) {
        var registrationForm = dojo.filter(modl, function(item) {
            return item.formnumber == 'XI00Z';
        });
        if (registrationForm.length > 0) {
            servDefinitions.Fee = registrationForm[0].CalculatedVariableFee;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < formsDef.length; i++) {
        formCode = formsDef[i].FormDefinitionID;
        for (var j = 0; j < modl.length; j++) {
            if (modl[j].formnumber == formCode) {
                //Attach some dynamic properties to the form definitions
                formsDef[i].pendingtaskid = modl[j].pendingtaskid;
                formsDef[i].iscomplete = modl[j].iscomplete;
                formsDef[i].drcorstatus = modl[j].drcorstatus;

                if ((!modl[j].isDocument) && (modl[j].Attachments.length > 0)) {
                    formsDef[i].DocumentGuid = modl[j].Attachments[0].DocumentID;
                }

                if (modl[j].iscomplete == 0) {
                    iscomplete = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.djtFormsList.IsCompleted(iscomplete);
    this.djtFormsList.SetServiceFormsDefinitions(servDefinitions);

    for (var i = 0; i < modl.length; i++) {
        if (modl[i].isDocument) {
            //Set the attachments for each document in the incomplete service form list
            this.djtFormsList.SetDocumentAttachments(modl[i].formnumber, modl[i].Attachments);
        }
    }

    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divServiceFormsDefinitions, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divIncompleteServices, "display", "none");
},

showIncompleteServices: function(inCompleteServices) {
    this.djtIncompleteServices.SetIncompleteServicesList(inCompleteServices);
    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divIncompleteServices, "display", "block");
},

showFormDefinitions: function() {
    this.djtFormsList.IsCompleted(false);
    glb_serviceInstanceID = 0;
    this.djtFormsList.SetServiceFormsDefinitions(this.servicesDefinitions[0]);
    this.djtFormsList.ClearDocumentAttachments();
    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divServiceFormsDefinitions, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divIncompleteServices, "display", "none");
},



onBack: function() {
    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divServiceFormsDefinitions, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divIncompleteServices, "display", "none");

    this.buildRendering();
    this.ShowServicesList(this.serviceTypeCode);
},

_ServiceCompleted: function() {
    glb_serviceInstanceID = 0;
    dojo.style(this.divBackButton, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divServices, "display", "block");
    dojo.style(this.divServiceFormsDefinitions, "display", "none");
    dojo.style(this.divIncompleteServices, "display", "none");

    this.buildRendering();
    this.ShowServicesList(this.serviceTypeCode);
    this.onServiceCompleted();
},

onServiceCompleted: function() {
}
});
```

Ok so now let me explain the problem.

When i run this application under internet explorer 8 or 7 everything works perfectly.
But when i try to open it using IE9, Firefox or Chrome i get an error stating that "djtServiceDetails is not defined".

As i understood from debugging this is because when the file is executed the **postCreate** part of the View is not executed (a debugger in the postCreate is never found)

I have a similar page using the same structure as the above that works in all browsers and we could not locate any differences.

I hope that you might be able to tell me something that will help me solve this issue.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Solon

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that may or may not work.  I tried reproducing your issue with simplified code and could not.  As a rule, I do not provide a constructor function in my custom widgets.  The code you have in the constructor can go in `postMixInProperties`.

Try changing your constructor function to the following:

```
postMixInProperties: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);

    this.controller = new js.Forms.Controllers.ServiceDetailsController(this);
    this.nlsStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("Resources", "Resources");
    var queryObj = Utils.General.GetQueryStringObject(window.location.href);
    this.isDissolved = queryObj
        [Utils.General.Constants.queryParameters.ISDISSOLVED];
},
```

I wonder if the dojo.i18n call, which will more than likely make an xhr request, causes the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a problem with the parsing of your markup.. Thats basically the biggest caveat, using dojo since DOCTYPE and rendering engines are the hardest parts to 'guard' against in platform independant JS. I havent used < 1.7 for a while now but im fairly certain that the proper markup would be closer to this, using camelCase syntax on the custom attributes:

```
<div id="ServiceDetails" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Services" style="height: 95%">
    <div id="divServiceDetails" runat="server">
        <div dojoType="js.Forms.ServiceDetails" jsId="djtServiceDetails" id="ServiceDetailsWdj">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="PendingTask" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Pending Tasks" style="height: 95%">
    <div id="divPendingTask" runat="server">
        <div dojoType="js.Forms.PendingServices" jsId="djtPendingServices" id="PendingTaskWdj">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="CertificatesList" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Certificates"
    style="height: 95%">
    <div id="divCertificatesList" runat="server">
        <div dojoType="js.Forms.CertificatesList">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will look messy either way through a validator =)

Again, with 1.6 im not sure but i think you could replace into html5 compat attribute naming schema, so that `dojoType` becomes `data-dojo-type` and `jsId`would be `data-dojo-jsId` (should look into these in reference api). In regards to jsId - you would be best off with referencing widgets through the dijit registry - the global scope exposure is on its way out in future versions. So instead of getting said object through `/*window.*/ djtServiceDetails`, call `dijit.byId('djtServiceDetails')`

Try it out, and with that said - i personally would also compile stuff like 'title', 'id', 'valueAttr' etc into the dojoProps attribute, so that:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" jsId="registryKeyId" title="Dia Title" href="index101.html"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" dojoProps="id:'registryKeyId', title:'Dia Title', href:'index101.html'"></div>
```